# When I install bootstrap by CDN, it shows me the error: failed to load resource: net::err_connection_reset

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-5

I try to install boostrap 5 in laravel project but it shows me this error in console:
`error failed to load resource: net::err_connection_reset`

I added codes CDN in HTML page:

`<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">`

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can't reproduce; both those resources load fine for me, and no messages in console. Maybe the CDN blocked you for some reason.

Comment: you are right because when I copy the link of Bootstrap in google chrome it doesn't work it shows me "the site can't be reached"  
What should I do?

Comment: Can't tell you what the problem on your end could be, you'd have to go investigate that further yourself. Any specific reason you are not working with local copies of those libraries?

Comment: I solved it by downloading Bootstrap and putting the file css in public folder in Laravel
it worked for me now